# Использую агрегирование в PHP, как правильно указать интерфейс?

Tags: php

Например, есть такая ситуация.

```php
interface ITest
{
    public function test();
}

class Test implements ITest
{
    ...
}

interface ITest2 extends ITest
{
    public function test($a = '');
}

class Test2 extends Test implements ITest2
{
    ...
}

class WorkWithTest
{
    protected ITest $var;

    public function __construct($test)
    {
        $this->var = $test;
    }
}

class WorkWithTest2 extends WorkWithTest
{
    protected ITest2 $var; //PHP Fatal error:  Type of WorkWithTest2::$var must be ITest

    public function __construct($test2)
    {
        $this->var = $test2;
    }
}
```

Как в класс `WorkWithTest2` сделать так, чтобы он работал только с инстансами, что реализуют интерфейс ITest2?

Comment: А так `if (! ($test2 instanceof ITest2)) { throw new Exception("Not correct"); }`

Comment: @splash58, как вариант. По другому никак?

Comment: а в конструкторе тип указать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что-то не очень могу понять, как именно? Можно, пожалуйста, пример?

Comment: `public function __construct(ITest2 $test2)`

Comment: Спасибо. Это выглядит хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте свойство приватным:

```
interface ITest
{
    public function test();
}

class Test implements ITest
{
    ...
}

interface ITest2 extends ITest
{
    public function test($a = '');
}

class Test2 extends Test implements ITest2
{
    ...
}

class WorkWithTest
{
    private ITest $var;

    public function __construct($test)
    {
        $this->var = $test;
    }
}

class WorkWithTest2 extends WorkWithTest
{
    private ITest2 $var; //PHP Fatal error:  Type of WorkWithTest2::$var must be ITest

    public function __construct($test2)
    {
        $this->var = $test2;
    }
}
```

Ваша проблема в том, что вы используете наследование, однако, в этом нет смысла, оно вам только мешает.

Если вы не используете свойство правильно в контексте наследования, то не нужно вовсе его наследовать.